# Distinct count over two tables. SQL

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I'm very new to SQL, I apologize if something doesn't make sense!

I have `two tables` each of which has a column `'client_nbr'`. Some of the `client_nbrs` will `overlap` in the two tables. I'm needing to `count` the number of people with a certain value in column `'age'` that is in both tables. For example, the results should have something like

```
age - 5 count - 3,000
```

And that will only count a client number once, even if it is in both tables.

When I do this for one table I run:

```
Select age, count(distinct(client_nbr))
From table1
Group by age
```

I tried to follow the example here: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/07/sql-server-distinct-count-multiple.html?m=1

Using:

```
Select table1.age,table2.age,
Count(distinct(table1.client_nbr)) as total
From table1,table2
Where table1.client_nbr=table2.client_nbr
Group by table1.age,table2.age
```

It didn't work out though. The total count was less than when I run a distinct count on just table1.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It will be good if edit your questions with **Sample data** of both the tables and **expected output**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(DISTINCT client_nbr) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT age, client_nbr FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT age, client_nbr FROM table2
) AS t
GROUP BY age
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an implicit inner join in your query meaning only the values contained in both tables are returned.  Use an outer join to get all the values in both tables

```
Select table1.age,table2.age,
Count(distinct(table1.client_nbr)) as total
From table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.age = table2.age
Group by table1.age,table2.age
```